# Adding logo on Page header in Export to word using Open Xml SDK - File is opening but logo is not added

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, sdk

I am using the below code to add the Image.Jpg to the page header and no header value is showing. it is showing blank.

I have other text items in the content and they are all showing up but not the image in the page header. Need solutions please.

```
        HeaderPart headerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();                
                string logoRld = "rId" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                GenerateHeaderPart1Content(headerPart, ImagePath, logoRld);
                HeaderReference headerReference = new HeaderReference() { Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = "rId1" }; // mainPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart) };
                SectionProperties sectionProperties = new SectionProperties(headerReference);
                mainPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProperties);

                static void GenerateHeaderPart1Content(HeaderPart headerPart, string imagepath, string logoRld)
                {

                    ImagePart imagePart = headerPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg, "rId1");
                    SetImagePartContent(imagePart, imagepath);

                    Drawing drawing = new Drawing();
                    Inline inline = new Inline(
                        new Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
                        new DocProperties(),
                        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Graphic(
                            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.GraphicData(
                                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures.Picture(
                                        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BlipFill(
                                        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip() { Embed = "rId2" },
                                        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Stretch(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.FillRectangle())),
                                    new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ShapeProperties(
                                        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.NoFill()
                                        )))));
                  
                    drawing.Append(inline);
                    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(drawing);
                    headerPart.Header = new Header(paragraph);



                }
                static void SetImagePartContent(ImagePart imagePart, string imagepath)
                {
                    using (FileStream inFile = new FileStream(imagepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        byte[] byteArray = new byte[inFile.Length];
                        inFile.Read(byteArray, 0, (int)inFile.Length);
                        imagePart.FeedData(new MemoryStream(byteArray));


                    }
                }
```

I am using   using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(memStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)) to Create a word document using Open Xml Sdk. Need help in adding Image to the header.

Comment: How can i resolve the above issue. Any ideas please.

Comment: I do not know the language you are using. Learn the Word object model which has terms for each of the types of headers and footers.

Comment: C# , I am using openxml sdk

Comment: Look in the Developer Network about header storyranges. There are three: wdPrimaryHeaderStory, wdEvenPagesHeaderStory, wdFirstPageHeaderStory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.storyranges?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158007352)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue You may want to consult John Korchok's OOXML Hacking.